# How to update song information after editing outside of iTunes?

Tags: windows, itunes

I use iTunes on Windows to manage all my songs, but I don't allow iTunes to copy the songs into iTunes' media folder. Sometimes I edit the song information (e.g. title, artist) directly from Windows Explorer instead of using iTunes. However, iTunes does not show the changes. How can I let it happen?

I already know these two methods, but they are not good at all.

1. Delete the entire library and read again. Adding songs to library takes hours even if I do not let iTunes copy songs to the media folder, since I have thousands of songs.
2. Right click the updated song and click *Get Info*. iTunes will update the information automatically. However, this way, I need to remember and find which songs I have edited. (If I select multiple songs at same time and click *Get Info*, iTunes will not update the information.)